# Elasticsearch: does not give back result when searching for a simple 'a' character

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store tags for messages in ElasticSearch. I've defined the tags field as this:

```
{
  'tags': {
    'type': 'string',
    'index_name': 'tag'
  }
}
```

For a message I've stored the following list in the tags field:

```
['a','b','c']
```

Now if I try to search for tag 'b' with the following query, it gives back the message and the tags:

```
{
  'filter': {
    'limit': {
      'value': 100
    }
  },
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {
          'text': {
            'tags': 'b'
          }
        }
      ],
      'minimum_number_should_match': 1
    }
  }
}
```

There goes the same with tag 'c'.
But if I search for tag 'a' with this:

```
{
  'filter': {
    'limit': {
      'value': 100
    }
  },
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {
          'text': {
            'tags': 'a'
          }
        }
      ],
      'minimum_number_should_match': 1
    }
  }
}
```

It gives back no results at all! 
The answer is:

```
{
  'hits': {
    'hits': [],
    'total': 0,
    'max_score': None
  },
  '_shards': {
    'successful': 5,
    'failed': 0,
    'total': 5
  },
  'took': 1,
  'timed_out': False
}
```

What am I doing wrong? (It doesn't matter that the 'a' is the first element of the list, the same goes for ['b','a','c']. It seems it has problems only with a single 'a' character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't set any analyzer and mapping to your index, Elasticsearch uses its own analyzer by default. Elasticsearch's `default_analyzer` has stopwords filter that defaultly ignores English stopwords such as:

```
   "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
  "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
  "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
  "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
  "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
```

Before going for more just check ElasticSearch mapping and analyzer guides:

- [Analyzer Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/)
- [Mapping Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/)

Answer (score 0):

There might be some stemming or stop word lists involved. Try making sure the field is not analyzed.

```
'tags': {'type': 'string', 'index_name': 'tag', "index" : "not_analyzed"}
```

Similar: [matching whole string with dashes in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978508/matching-whole-string-with-dashes-in-elasticsearch/17032052#17032052)